# Web Scraping a whole page with Scrapy and CSS Selectors

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape all of the text in an html page at once.  I know i will have a lot of extra information and that it will not be organized, but i am trying to see if there is some way to scrape multiple websites at once with one scraper.

The problem is when i run the Scrapy spider in Python i get all the spaces : that i do not need as well as as extra information about the page even if I specified that i only wanted to extract the text in my code.

I tried making my CSS selectors more specific but I always end up with no information at all or not enough information

```
import scrapy
from ..items import WholePageItem

class WholePageSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whole_page_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.justanexample.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = WholePageItem()
        mission = response.css('body').css('::text').extract()

        items['mission'] = mission

        yield items
```

The output of the extraction is this:

```
   'THE GOOD TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT',
         '\n',
         '\n',
         '\n',
         'window.purechatApi = { l: [], t: [], on: function () { '
         'this.l.push(arguments); } }; (function () { var done = false; '
         "var script = document.createElement('script'); script.async = "
         "true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = "
         "'https://blablabla.com'; "
         "document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); "
         'script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if '
         "(!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || "
         "this.readyState == 'complete')) { var w = new PCWidget({c: "
         "'3a6f7d8e-a107-4582-b33c-c10aa2b80ac8', f: true }); done = true; "
         '} }; })();',
         '\n',
```

What am i trying to get is only this part:
  'THE GOOD TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT',

I do not need to be specific,the only thing i dont want is the '\n', as well as the code in the code.

What can i do? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Celery along with redis to scrape multiple webpages asynchronously and in a scheduled manner if you want. Besides also go through beautiful soup for a better understanding of scraping. In this case just to get the expected text you can use the split method like

```
list_separated_by_comma_words = sometext.split(',')
```

You can not access every expected words by indexing. Like to get this 'THE GOOD TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT' you can do -

```
list_separated_by_comma_words[0]
```

To split by '\n' you can do the same. But if you want to strip '\n' you can use the `.strip()` method as well.